# IntelliJ - test configuration. How to configure once run for everyone?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I want to run JUnit tests in IntelliJ separately. I need to pass special configuration to run them. Everytime I want to run new test I have to create new run configuration. I need to pass VM argument:  -`Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox_16en\firefox.exe"` as well as `Environment variables`.

How do I define those configuration details once and the just run the particular test I want with those settings?

Comment: Did you try to create a [run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-run-debug-configuration-for-tests.html)?

Comment: Yes, but there I create configuration for all tests. Then I want to run a particular test and the configuration is not taken from the all tests configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you want to change the default run/debug configuration settings, expand the Defaults node, select the desired configuration type, and modify it as required.

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

Open `Run > Edit Configurations`. Select `Defaults > JUnit` in the left tree and add your VM arguments. Those arguments will be used for every new JUnit run configuration automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it's not the best solution that can be imagine, but it fits my needs :)

Comment: Those Default Run Configurations will be attached only to this project, right? Not to the whole IntelliJ instance?

Comment: Yes, default run configurations are applied to your current project only. They are saved in `.idea/workspace.xml`.